# Spring customised PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring

I have config xml based spring application for which I have moved proprties required at start up time in database. It was very difficult to manage hundreds in property file and that is why database is introduced. To read properties a spring restful service is developed to return a map of all properties required at start up time.

I want to know how to replace properties reading from a map to spring context file e.g. ${config.service.url} should be polulated from a map read via web service.

One option I considered is to upgrade to Annotation based and start using MapPropertySource and Environment interface as environment.getRequiredProperty("config.service.url"). However upgrading to Annotation based is a big impact on project and is no at this time.

Second option that I am looking forward is to have a customised PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Any pointer/help on this will be great.

Cheers,

Amber

Comment: One silly way is to call your web service in a seperated app, generate a file with properties, read the file from your final application with a PropertyPlaceholder.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but instead of specifying a file location, you can pass the properties directly as returned by your restful service.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="properties" .../>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi, yes I am looking forward for such implementation. By any chance do you have a sample implemation for above to populate properties at run time ? I am also considering Mapconfiguration as below                                                             <bean id =  "mapConfiguration" class = "org.apache.commons.configuration.MapConfiguration">
         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="restPropertyMap"/>
    </bean>